# How to overwrite array elements in PyOpenCL

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, pyopencl

I'd like to overwrite part of a PyOpenCL array with another array.
Let's say

```
import numpy as np, pyopencl.array as cla
a = cla.zeros(queue,(3,3),'int8')
b = cla.ones(queue,(2,2),'int8')
```

Now I want to do something like `a[0:2,0:2] = b` and hopefully get

```
1 1 0
1 1 0
0 0 0
```

How would I do that without copying everything to the host for speed reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Pyopencl arrays are able to do that - **to a very limited extent at the time of this answer** - with the numpy syntax (ie exactly how you wrote it) the limitation being: you can only use slices along the first axis.

```
import numpy as np, pyopencl.array as cla

a = cla.zeros(queue,(3,3),'int8')
b = cla.ones(queue,(2,3),'int8')
# note b is 2x3 here 
a[0:2]=b #<-works
a[0:2,0:2]=b[:,0:2] #<-Throws an error about non-contiguity
```

So `a[0:2,0:2] = b` won't work as the destination sliced array have non-contiguous data.

The only solution I am aware of (**as nothing in the pyopencl.array class is yet able to work with sliced arrays/non-contiguous data**), is to write your own openCL kernel to do the copy "by hand".

Here is a piece of code I use to do copies on 1D or 2D pyopencl arrays of all dtype:

```
import numpy as np, pyopencl as cl, pyopencl.array as cla
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
kernel = cl.Program(ctx, """__kernel void copy(
            __global char *dest,      const int offsetd, const int stridexd, const int strideyd,
            __global const char *src, const int offsets, const int stridexs, const int strideys,
            const int word_size) {

            int write_idx = offsetd + get_global_id(0) + get_global_id(1) * stridexd + get_global_id(2) * strideyd ;
            int read_idx  = offsets + get_global_id(0) + get_global_id(1) * stridexs + get_global_id(2) * strideys;
            dest[write_idx] =  src[read_idx];

            }""").build()

def copy(dest,src):
    assert dest.dtype == src.dtype
    assert dest.shape == src.shape
    if len(dest.shape) == 1 :
        dest.shape=(dest.shape[0],1)
        src.shape=(src.shape[0],1)
        dest.strides=(dest.strides[0],0)
        src.strides=(src.strides[0],0)
    kernel.copy(queue, (src.dtype.itemsize,src.shape[0],src.shape[1]), None, dest.base_data, np.uint32(dest.offset), np.uint32(dest.strides[0]), np.uint32(dest.strides[1]), src.base_data, np.uint32(src.offset), np.uint32(src.strides[0]), np.uint32(src.strides[1]), np.uint32(src.dtype.itemsize))


a = cla.zeros(queue,(3,3),'int8')
b = cla.ones(queue,(2,2),'int8')

copy(a[0:2,0:2],b)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the pyopencl mailing list, Andreas Klöckner gave me a hint: there's an undocumented function in `pyopencl.array` called `multiput()`. Syntax is like this:

```
cla.multi_put([arr],indices,out=[out])
```

'arr' is the source array, 'out' is the destination array and 'indices' is a 1D array of ints (also on the device) which contains the linear element indices counted row-major.

For example, in my first post, indices for putting 'b' into 'a' would be (0, 1, 3, 4). You just need to put together your indices somehow and can use multiput() instead of writing a kernel. `len(indices)` must of course be equal to `b.size`. There's also a `take()` and `multitake()` function for reading elements from an array.

Comment: "Thanks" and other conversational things are not desirable in answers.